# nginxで一部のURLへアクセスした場合のみdjangoアプリケーションへ接続させたい

Tags: centos, nginx, django

静的なhtmlが大半を占めるウェブサイトでDjangoアプリケーションを組み込むこととなりましたが、`http://example.com/contact`や`http://example.com/contact/<id>`の場合のみDjangoアプリケーションにアクセスさせるにはnginx.confをどのように改修すれば良いでしょうか。

Djangoアプリケーション自体はすでにデプロイ済みです。
また、下記のconfファイルをnginx.confのhttp{ }にincludeさせています。

```
upstream django {
    server x.x.x.x:8000;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xx.xx.xxx.xxx;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location /static {
        alias /opt/django/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include    /opt/django/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記のような感じでいけると思います。

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xx.xx.xxx.xxx;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location /static {
        alias /opt/django/static;
    }

    location ~ /(contact|extra)/ {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include    /opt/django/uwsgi_params;
    }

    location / {
         root /var/www/html;
    }
}
```

複数のパスでDjangoアプリに流したい場合も考慮して正規表現でURLパスをマッチしています。

この例ですと下記のようなアクセスになります。

```
http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/contact/  # => contact以下全てを Djangoアプリ にプロキシ
http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/extra/    # => extra以下全てを Djangoアプリ にプロキシ
http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/          # => それ以外を /var/www/html 以下のコンテンツから取得
```